# How can I know when there is a new line on a Wheel of Fortune Board?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I the following code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XP9Qv/19/) in which you can play a Wheel of Fortune-like game with one person (more of my test of javascript objects).

My issue is that when the screen is small enough, the lines do not seem to break correctly.

For example:

[image]

Where the circle is, I have a "blank" square. The reason why I have a blank square is so that when the screen is big enough, the square serves as a space between the words.

Is there a way in my code to efficiently know if the blank square is at the end of the line and to not show it, and then the window gets resized, to show it accordingly?

The only thought I had was to add a `window.onresize` event which would measure how big the words are related to how big the playing space is and decide based on that fact, but that seems very inefficient.

This is my code for creating the game board (starts @ line 266 in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XP9Qv/19/)):

```
WheelGame.prototype.startRound = function (round) {
    this.round = round;
    this.lettersInPuzzle = [];
    this.guessedArray = [];
    this.puzzleSolved = false;
    this.currentPuzzle = this.puzzles[this.round].toUpperCase();
    this.currentPuzzleArray = this.currentPuzzle.split("");
    var currentPuzzleArray = this.currentPuzzleArray;
    var lettersInPuzzle = this.lettersInPuzzle;
    var word = document.createElement('div');
    displayArea.appendChild(word);
    word.className = "word";
    for (var i = 0; i < currentPuzzleArray.length; ++i) {
        var span = document.createElement('div');
        span.className = "wordLetter ";

        if (currentPuzzleArray[i] != " ") {
            span.className += "letter";
            if (!(currentPuzzleArray[i] in lettersInPuzzle.toObject())) {
                lettersInPuzzle.push(currentPuzzleArray[i]);
            }
            word.appendChild(span);
        } else {
            span.className += "space";
            word = document.createElement('div');
            displayArea.appendChild(word);
            word.className = "word";
            word.appendChild(span);
            word = document.createElement('div');
            displayArea.appendChild(word);
            word.className = "word";
        }

        span.id = "letter" + i;
    }

    var clear = document.createElement('div');
    displayArea.appendChild(clear);
    clear.className = "clear";
};
```

Comment: @Yoshi ahhh, but how do I know when the element is **on** a new line?

Comment: @Yoshi could  you post as an answer with some code so I can _try_ to understand?

Comment: @Yoshi :-( please try not to? (if you can) ^_^ [I am going for some library-less code :-D]

Comment: @Yoshi I am sure it will be awesome ^_^

Comment: @Neal you should be able to convert the jQuery to vanilla code quite easily.

Comment: @rlemon yea. I know :-) Hence I would be good with any answer :-D

Comment: Do we even need JS for this …? Please have a look at this fiddle, and tell me if it behaves as you’d like it to when you change the width of the result iframe: http://jsfiddle.net/CBroe/Wrddz/

Comment: @CBroe your words do not break correctly.

Comment: What would be “correctly” then by your definition?

Comment: @CBroe whole words do not stay on the line together

Comment: This better …? http://jsfiddle.net/CBroe/Wrddz/1/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of JavaScript, this sounds more like a job for CSS, which solves this problem all the time when dealing with centered text.

Consider something like this:

**CSS**

```
#board {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 60pt;
}

.word {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Don't break up words */
    margin: 0 50px; /* The space between words */
}

.word span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="board">
    <span class="word"><span>W</span><span>h</span><span>e</span><span>e</span><span>l</span></span>
    <span class="word"><span>o</span><span>f</span></span>
    <span class="word"><span>F</span><span>o</span><span>r</span><span>t</span><span>u</span><span>n</span><span>e</span></span>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrW3E/) (try resizing the output pane).

Comment: This is the best answer if you are willing to refactor the code.  It'll make your program simpler to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.  Uses the `element.offsetTop` to determine if a `.space` element is on the same line as its `parent.previousSibling.lastChild` or `parent.nextSibling.firstChild`.

### Relevant Code

*Note: In the fiddle I change the background colors instead of changing display so you can see it work.*

```
// hides and shows spaces if they are at the edge of a line or not.
function showHideSpaces() {
    var space,
        spaces = document.getElementsByClassName('space');

    for (var i = 0, il = spaces.length ; i < il; i++) {
        space = spaces[i];
        // if still display:none, then offsetTop always 0.
        space.style.display = 'inline-block';

        if (getTop(nextLetter(space)) != space.offsetTop || getTop(prevLetter(space)) != space.offsetTop) {
            space.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            space.style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }
}

// navigate to previous letter
function nextLetter(fromLetter) {
    if (fromLetter.nextSibling) return fromLetter.nextSibling;
    if (fromLetter.parentElement.nextSibling) 
        return fromLetter.parentElement.nextSibling.firstChild;
    return null;
}

// navigate to next letter
function prevLetter(fromLetter) {
    if (fromLetter.previousSibling) return fromLetter.previousSibling;
    if (fromLetter.parentElement.previousSibling)
        return fromLetter.parentElement.previousSibling.lastChild;
    return null;
}

// get offsetTop
function getTop(element) {
    return (element) ? element.offsetTop : 0;
}

showHideSpaces();
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('resize', showHideSpaces);
else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onresize', showHideSpaces);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XP9Qv/24/)

Comment: That is pretty pretty cool :-D. Now I just have to make it so that space elements at the start/end of the line are not displayed :-)

Comment: Also I probably do not want this in an interval. Probably only on window resize.

Comment: @neal:  I got confused.  The reason why I am doing with the interval is in case the parent element got resized.  For example if somebody changed font sizes then would window.resize event get fired?  Or if you change another element's width and it causes display's the change as a side effect.

Comment: Ehhh that _seems_ like too much. I really do not see the need for the interval bc none of those cases happen here...

Comment: @Neal I went ahead and removed `setInterval` from the answer.  I also changed the code a bit to be more extensible.